# Azure AD Graph API - Adding user to application gets PlatformNotSupportedException

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

My goal is to add a user to an application in Azure.

I'm using the old Azure AD Graph API only for this method, because the newer Microsoft Graph API currently doesn't support this feature.

By process of elimination, I've found that the error occurs right at the beginning, when trying to get the user by id.

The error I get is;

```
System.InvalidOperationException: An error occurred while processing this request. ---> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Secure binary serialization is not supported on this platform.
```

My code for the method;

```
public async Task AddUserToService(string userId)
{
    try
    {
        var user = await activeDirectoryClient.Users.GetByObjectId(userId).ExecuteAsync() as User;

        var appRoleAssignment = new AppRoleAssignment()
        {
            ResourceId = Guid.Parse(applicationId),
            PrincipalId = Guid.Parse(userId),
            Id = Guid.Parse(roleId)
        };

        user.AppRoleAssignments.Add(appRoleAssignment);
        await user.UpdateAsync();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.Log(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Error, "Error occurred during retrieval; " + e);
    }
}
```

Comment: What platform are you running this app on? Windows?

Comment: @juunas Yes, Windows.

Comment: Are you using .NET Core? I think I have seen that with .NET Core before

Comment: @RohitSaigal I'm using .NET Standard 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a direct rest httpClient call against the old graph.

I am only posting this as a reference - notice the explicit version on the url (1.6). I am also posting the object i deserialize into, this may not match the official object schema.

```
// OLD Graph End point    //  like ... https://graph.windows.net/{tenant-id}/users/{id}/appRoleAssignments?api-version=1.6
   urlUserInviteToUse = "https://graph.windows.net/" + m_CfgHlp.TenIdInB2C + "/" + ObjFamilyName + "/" + DirObjIdToGet + "/" + ObjFunctionCall + "?api-version=1.6";
```

Due to the rest api string payload I am effectively using the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to go from payload to object class. Notice that the Dates are not being deserialized as dates.

```
public class AppRoleAssignmentsRoot
{
    public string odatametadata { get; set; }
    public AppRoleAssignment[] value { get; set; }
}

public class AppRoleAssignment
{
    public string odatatype { get; set; }
    public string objectType { get; set; }
    public string objectId { get; set; }
    public object deletionTimestamp { get; set; }
    public object creationTimestamp { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string principalDisplayName { get; set; }
    public string principalId { get; set; }
    public string principalType { get; set; }
    public string resourceDisplayName { get; set; }
    public string resourceId { get; set; }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I ended up using a similar approach, but completely removing the Azure AD Graph API library and simply using HttpClient to post directly to the old graph like you.

Comment: Glad to know it helped :)