# Exception in Query Azure Active AD users using C# code

Tags: c#, exception, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have registered an app in Azure Active Diretcory and using below code:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="TenantId" value="b1f9cb25-7c7a-4ecd-96c1-513c2b42c350"/>
    <add key="TenantName" value="myTentantName.onmicrosoft.com"/>
    <add key="ClientId" value="d82c0c6a-8c14-4c42-8aca-60c79fcfc9b4"/>
    <add key="ClientSecret" value="27?_MOh_qM633Hcccct;cw:@*$9ojcsNxve)rYI"/>
</appSettings>

internal class Settings
{
    public const string ResourceUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
    public static string TenantId => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TenantId"];
    public static string TenantName => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TenantName"];
    public static string ClientId => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
    public static string ClientSecret => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"];
    public static string AuthString => "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + TenantName; 
}
```

class AuthenticationHelper

```
public static ActiveDirectoryClient GetActiveDirectoryClientAsApplication()
{
    Uri servicePointUri = new Uri(Settings.ResourceUrl);
    Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(servicePointUri, Settings.TenantId);
    ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(
        serviceRoot,
        async () => await AcquireTokenAsyncForApplication());
    return activeDirectoryClient;
}

private static async Task<string> AcquireTokenAsyncForApplication()
{
    AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(Settings.AuthString, false);

    ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(Settings.ClientId, Settings.ClientSecret);
    AuthenticationResult authenticationResult =
        await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(
            Settings.ResourceUrl,
            clientCred);
    string token = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
    return token;
}
```

main class

```
var client = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClientAsApplication();

try
{
    var users = await client.Users.OrderBy(user => user.DisplayName).ExecuteAsync();
    var foundUser = await client.Users.Where(user => user.ObjectId == "d62d8c6a-dc69-46c1-99c4-36cd672f0c12").ExecuteAsync();
    foreach (var user in users.CurrentPage)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(user.DisplayName + " " + user.ObjectId);
    }
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exception);
}
```

I am getting an error in main class in line :

```
var users = await client.Users.OrderBy(user => user.DisplayName).ExecuteAsync();
```

System.InvalidOperationException: An error occurred while processing this request.
 ---> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Secure binary serialization is not supported on this platform.

[image]

Comment: Use debugger to make sure client has all the values it needs to successfully connect and retrieve users

Comment: Attched the screenshot of client value during debug in the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure AD Graph API - Adding user to application gets PlatformNotSupportedException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55262235/azure-ad-graph-api-adding-user-to-application-gets-platformnotsupportedexcepti)

Comment: Nope, actually code is not showing any Http request instead of AD microsoft graph

Answer (score 1):

I got a success by referring to the official sample: [Azure-Samples
/
active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console/tree/archive)

[image]

The only difference is that the `ResourceUrl` is not  `https://graph.microsoft.com`. The correct value is `https://graph.windows.net`.

That makes sense. Because you are trying to use [AD Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api) not [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph)

---

Update

As in the code, you are acquiring the token with client credential. So, the token you get only has application permission. So, you need to add and grant application permission in Azure portal:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot but unable to install Nuget Package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory & Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient . Its showing error as Specified file name is too long while installing the package and restoring.

Comment: I am getting below error:  Error getting User
    AADSTS90002: Tenant 'myTestApp' not found. This may happen if there are no active subscriptions for the tenant. Check to make sure you have the correct tenant ID. Check with your subscription administrator.
Trace ID: xxxx-a503-4c75-8a6e-3c0cc4703600
Correlation ID: xxxxxxxxx-4675-93b2-aeb7a94ecdcb
Timestamp: 2020-01-31 13:45:19Z

Comment: Anyways after changing the Tenant ID with value in Directory ID ( App properties)   I got below error:  Error getting User
Request ID: xxxxxx-a899-4b78-b2d5-66fe081257f7
Date: 2020-01-31T13:48:19

    An error occurred while processing this request.

        {"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."},"requestId":"xxxxxx-a899-4b78-b2d5-66fe081257f7","date":"2020-01-31T13:48:19"}}

Comment: Check if you have add necessary app permissions for your registered application in portal.

Comment: Attached is the permission screenshot of the app in the Question. Only User.Read is having permission.

Comment: @AllTech You need to add application permission as you are getting token with client credential.

Comment: Yes, i need to use Microsoft Graph to achieve my task.

Answer (score 1):

Now that the wrong resource issue was spotted code works well (I tested it myself). What are the remaining issues?

- Specified file name is too long? This is due Windows [Maximum Path Length Limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation). Move your repo files up the closest to your drive or root folder path.
- [AADSTS90002](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-aadsts-error-codes#aadsts-error-codes)? Try using the tenand Id instead of the full name.
- Authorization_RequestDenied is due lack of permissions, ensure you're setting and consenting the required ones, for your code you need `https://graph.windows.net/Directory.Read.All`.
  Finally you can get users with both AAD Graph API and MS Graph API. The recommendation is to move to the later since the former is going to be deprecated. Take a look to [Migrate Azure AD Graph apps to Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/migrate-azure-ad-graph-overview).